# packer builder source_ami_filter for ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: amazon-web-services, packer

i am trying my hands on packer.

i was able to create an image for ubuntu 16.04 by

```
"source_ami_filter": {
          "filters": {
            "virtualization-type": "hvm",
            "name": "ubuntu/images/*ubuntu-xenial-16.04-amd64-server-*",
            "root-device-type": "ebs"
          },
```

but when it try the same filer by modifying 16.04 to 18.04

```
"source_ami_filter": {
          "filters": {
            "virtualization-type": "hvm",
            "name": "ubuntu/images/*ubuntu-xenial-18.04-amd64-server-*",
            "root-device-type": "ebs"
          },
```

i get the below error .

```
==> amazon-ebs: Prevalidating any provided VPC information
==> amazon-ebs: Prevalidating AMI Name: packer-example 1592389575
==> amazon-ebs: No AMI was found matching filters: {
==> amazon-ebs:   Filters: [{
==> amazon-ebs:       Name: "virtualization-type",
==> amazon-ebs:       Values: ["hvm"]
==> amazon-ebs:     },{
==> amazon-ebs:       Name: "name",
==> amazon-ebs:       Values: ["ubuntu/images/*ubuntu-xenial-18.04-amd64-server-*"]
==> amazon-ebs:     },{
==> amazon-ebs:       Name: "root-device-type",
==> amazon-ebs:       Values: ["ebs"]
==> amazon-ebs:     }],
==> amazon-ebs:   Owners: ["099720109477"]
==> amazon-ebs: }
Build 'amazon-ebs' errored: No AMI was found matching filters: {
  Filters: [{
      Name: "virtualization-type",
      Values: ["hvm"]
    },{
      Name: "name",
      Values: ["ubuntu/images/*ubuntu-xenial-18.04-amd64-server-*"]
    },{
      Name: "root-device-type",
      Values: ["ebs"]
    }],
  Owners: ["099720109477"]
}

==> Some builds didn't complete successfully and had errors:
--> amazon-ebs: No AMI was found matching filters: {
  Filters: [{
      Name: "virtualization-type",
      Values: ["hvm"]
    },{
      Name: "name",
      Values: ["ubuntu/images/*ubuntu-xenial-18.04-amd64-server-*"]
    },{
      Name: "root-device-type",
      Values: ["ebs"]
    }],
  Owners: ["099720109477"]
}
```

Wanted to how filter values work :

1. for 18.04 ?
2. for another other image(linux/redhat) ?

Could some one please clear the doubt i have with regards to this ?

Comment: 18.04 is code named `bionic`. 16.04 was codenamed `xenial`. Updating to `ubuntu/images/*ubuntu-bionic-18.04-amd64-server-*` should fix that for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Important note: you should set an **owners** attribute as I have in my examples here or you'll open yourself to bringing in malicious AMIs matching your pattern. The **name** field is user-controlled and not checked.

Update: Since this is about Packer and not Terraform here is the packer solution:

```
"source_ami_filter": {
  "filters": {
    "virtualization-type": "hvm",
    "architecture": "x86_64",
    "name": "ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-bionic-18.04-amd64-server-*",
    "block-device-mapping.volume-type": "gp2",
    "root-device-type": "ebs"
  },
  "owners": ["099720109477"],
  "most_recent": true
},
```

And here is my well-intentioned, but off-topic Terraform solution:

> ```
> data "aws_ami" "ubuntu-18_04" {
>   most_recent = true
>   owners = ["${var.ubuntu_account_number}"]
>
>   filter {
>     name   = "name"
>     values = ["ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-bionic-18.04-amd64-server-*"]
>   }
> }
>
> variable "ubuntu_account_number" {
>   default = "099720109477"
> }
> ```

Or if you want to encrypt it with your own KMS CMK:

> ```
> resource "aws_ami_copy" "ubuntu-18_04-encrypted" {
>   name              = "${data.aws_ami.ubuntu-18_04.name}-encrypted"
>   description       = "${data.aws_ami.ubuntu-18_04.description} (encrypted)"
>   source_ami_id     = "${data.aws_ami.ubuntu-18_04.id}"
>   source_ami_region = "${var.region}"
>   encrypted         = true
>
>   tags {
>     ImageType      = "encrypted-ubuntu-18_04"
>   }
> }
>
> data "aws_ami" "ubuntu-18_04" {
>   most_recent = true
>   owners = ["${var.ubuntu_account_number}"]
>
>   filter {
>     name   = "name"
>     values = ["ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-bionic-18.04-amd64-server-*"]
>   }
> }
>
> variable "ubuntu_account_number" {
>   default = "099720109477"
> }
> ```

I quoted these from my [Terraform: Latest Ubuntu 18.04 LTS encrypted AMI gist on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/AlainODea/be4fd6fc53bfbbcad45a7a9989db6c4e).

Comment: This is a Terraform example, not a Packer example? The question shouldn't be tagged Terraform because it's purely a Packer question really. It should also probably be closed because it's just a small mistake around naming of Ubuntu distributions.

Comment: Good catch. I've added the Packer piece and kept the Terraform piece. Since OP accepted the answer I didn't want to remove the original answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here, in 2021, we are using Packer HCL2 language and Ubuntu 20.04 and support multiply architectures

```
variable "arch" {
  type    = string
  default = "${env("ARCH")}"
}

source "amazon-ebs" "ubuntu" {

  source_ami_filter {
    filters = {
      name = "ubuntu/images/*ubuntu-focal-20.04-*-server-*"
      architecture = "${var.arch}"
      root-device-type = "ebs"
      virtualization-type = "hvm"
    }

    most_recent = true
    owners = ["099720109477"]
  }
}
```